# Print bootstrap striped table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a report that contains a table striped. I need to print the table with striped lines.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6.

I did:

```
@media print {    
    .table.table-striped td:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
}
```

But it did not work.

If I switch to striping columns (tr), works. Sorry for the English, I'm using a translator.

Comment: Just FYI, `<tr>` is a _table row_ not a column

Comment: See, I print the color blue, but red lines not. http://jsfiddle.net/pfdiass/1kvmjwxa/2/

Comment: I want to only the lines in red. The blue color was to exemplify what I got so far.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/1kvmjwxa/4/) what you want?

Comment: @Meeseeks That's it! Thank you so much! I put -webkit-print-color-adjust to force the display colors. http://jsfiddle.net/pfdiass/1kvmjwxa/5/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it with the following article: https://www.api2pdf.com/solved-bootstrap-striped-table-not-printing-to-pdf/

Code:

```
@media print {
   tr:nth-child(even) td {
       background-color: red !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

Comment: The link out to the article is fine but you shouldn't assume the site the site will always be up. It's important to include a summary of what makes it work.

Comment: This worked for me!!! Thanks. To be precise the -webkit setting made it work. I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

2020-11 - Bootstrap 4.5.0

- only thing that worked is adding background to `td` insted of `tr`.
- tested in Chrome, Vivaldi and Puppeteer

```css
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't force background colors to print. The browser would need to turn that option on.
Idea being you are not paying for their printer ink.

/* EDITED: April 20th */
I came across this same problem and a teammate showed me the -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; rule. I misspoke and this is possible. Looks like @mr-meeseeks Should get the points for their answer in the comments.

Comment: I need it because it is a customer requirement. The table has many rows and coloring lines facilitates to view the report.

Comment: the blue color was to exemplify what I got.

Comment: Not true, you can set background colors using the CSS media query `@media print`.